# rolling less than 13 months in sql

Tags: sql-server, date, advanced-custom-fields

I have a very tricky question here. I know how to write a rolling months in SQl but the thing now is how can i write rolling less than 13 months. For example : How should i write rolling months for less than 13 months. for example April 1 2018 to march 21 2017. I know how to write rolling months like april 18 to april 17 or march 17. If someone can help me with this that would be great. Thanks!!

```
DECLARE @Date DATE
declare @BeginDate varchar(100)                                                                             
declare @EndDate varchar(100)

SELECT @BeginDate = DATEADD(MONTH, -12, CAST(dateadd(d,-(day(getdate()-1)),getdate()) AS date))                    
SELECT @EndDate = CAST(dateadd(d,-(day(getdate())),getdate()) AS DATE)
```

Comment: This sure looks like sqlserver and NOT mysql.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server, try this.

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, EOMONTH(DATEADD(mm, -14, GETDATE()))) AS StartOfMonth
SELECT EOMONTH(DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE())) AS EndOfMonth
```

Comment: That looks good. One more problem I have is I have to less than 13 months for a lookback in a rolling 12 months query.                    For example :  WTLossGoal.CONTACT_DATE between dateadd(month,-6,ALLPATIENTS.contact_date) and ALLPATIENTS.contact_date                                                         Here we have look back period of 6 months. I want the lookback period to be less than 13 . I tried many ways to make that happen but I was not successful. If you can help me that would be great.